# Configuration in Android Studio - Could not find or load Main class

Tags: android, android-studio

Am not sure what went wrong, but I am not able to execute the code in my Kotlin library any more. It's not an app with UI, but just a main class executing functions from other custom classes. Just practicing some data structures.

I noticed all the configurations were deleted when I opened AS today after upgrading my AS to 4.0. I am trying to set new config, but I am not able to select MainActivity as my main class in the config. When I run the app, I get "Could not find or load Main class" error.

Anything else that I need to set?

Below are snapshots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an android app, you have to add the app module. Click on the plus button and select android App and select app as the module in it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had tried Android App config, but I am not seeing Module or "app" in Module drop down. I am getting Error: Module not specified error.

Comment: I created another android project and copied the files over there... That seems to be working fine. Something looks messed up with my old project as I am not seeing .gradle files too in the directory.